# Function, for loop, which, pairtrading

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have a date set (df) with 4 columns: date, price_1, price_2, ratio
ratio = price_1/price_2 it has something to do with pairs trading. I need to determine when a position is opened, and closed. 
m = mean(ratio), s = sd(ratio), k =1
A position will be opened if the ratio exceeds m + 1*s or m-1*s; this stays opened until it meets the criteria to close which is when this ratio <= m. A position will also be opened if the price exceed m -1*s, and closed as soon as the ratio becomes >= m. Position consists of the opening point and closing point. the first time the ratio exceeds either m+1*s or m-1*s is the position 1 opening point, then it closes in the case of ratio > m+1*s when ratio <= m;  and the other way around if the ratio exceeds m-1*s then closing is at ratio >= m
so position1 consists 1&2 in which 1 is the opening and closing is point 2 when its it hits the mean (black line). s = (dashed lines). == mean can't be just because of floating points.

```
     open_upper <- which(retail_stocks$ratio > (m + k*s) )
     open_lower <- which(retail_stocks$ratio < (m - k*s) )
     close_upper <- which(retail_stocks$ratio <= m )
     close_lower <- which(retail_stocks$ratio >= m )
```

but now I need to find out the position 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. with the opening and closing i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
open_close_idx_list <- vector("list", 4)


open_close_idx_func <- function(df, m, k, s){

         list(open_upper = which(df$ratio > (m + k*s)),

              open_lower = which(df$ratio < (m - k*s)),

              close_upper = which(df$ratio <= m),

              close_lower =  which(df$ratio >= m))

}

# Note the arguments passed to this function represent m, k, and s, and have been arbitrarily chosen: 

open_close_idx_list <- open_close_idx_func(retail_stocks, .8, .2, .3)

retail_stocks[c(open_close_idx_list$open_upper),]

retail_stocks[c(open_close_idx_list$open_lower),]

retail_stocks[c(open_close_idx_list$close_upper),]

retail_stocks[c(open_close_idx_list$close_lower),]
```

Revised Input Data:

```
    retail_stocks <- structure(list(date = structure(c(7306, 7307, 7308, 7309, 7312, 7313, 7314, 7315, 7316, 7319, 7320, 7321, 7322, 7323, 7326, 7327, 7328, 7329, 7330, 7333), class = "Date"),
                                TGT = c(3.141479, 3.171741, 3.177794, 3.183848, 3.214115, 3.171741, 3.171741, 3.1899, 3.099107, 3.050683, 3.038576, 3.020419, 2.996207, 2.965943, 2.899359, 2.935676, 2.971996, 2.941731, 2.881201, 2.905412), WMT = c(3.880284, 3.880284, 3.859697, 3.818529, 3.869992, 3.767066, 3.767066, 3.808233, 3.664141, 3.612676, 3.674432, 3.633262, 3.571507, 3.581798, 3.489166, 3.489166, 3.509751, 3.447996, 3.468581, 3.489166),
                                ratio = c(0.809600276680779, 0.81739919036854, 0.82332732336243, 0.833789137125841, 0.830522388676773, 0.841965869459149, 0.841965869459149, 0.837632571326387, 0.845793598008374, 0.844438582369412, 0.826951213139881, 0.7, 0.83891953732696, 0.82805981800202, 0.830960464477758, 0.841368968974248, 0.846782578023341, 0.853171233377301, 0.830656974710984, 0.832695262994079)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: Hi Steffie, if my solution is suitable can you please accept it as answer ?

Comment: Sorry, I will! Not so familiar yet with stackoverfrlow.  Your solution solved the question I asked! Only the complete objective is a little more complex than Ive stated above.

Comment: @Eugenie open_upper_df <- retail_stocks[open_upper,]

Comment: Thanks this is a detail in the script and names, but the main problem is how to write a function to find the next position to open and close. Doing this for the complete data set.

Comment: Post an anonymised version of your dataset so I can replicate it. I will solve your problem quickly.

Comment: Can I send it here on stackoverflow? or by e-mail? Because i dont know how to upload the data set on stackoverflow.

Comment: Post it on stack overflow in your question, use dput(df) to get the structure printed to the console and then copy and paste that into your question above.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, but i have absolutely no idea how to princt the structure. It's a R.Data file.

Comment: use the function dput(df) on your dataframe and then copy and paste the output from the console

Comment: I tried, but it exceeds the maximum amount of characters; if I copy it to here; it's fairly big, but you kind of need that because there not that many opening and closing points in total.

Comment: go to your question and edit your question with the output. If the entire dataframe is too big take a subset tmp_df <- head(df, 20), just need to see the columns in order to interpret what you want.

Comment: I changed it, hopefully you have enough information!

Comment: Thank you so much for all the effort, but it's not completely right yet.. The first step is to identify when to open and close positions.
In this question, you will write functions to identify, for given values of k, m and s, when positions
will be opened and closed, and consequently also how many positions there will be.
Remember that each position is dened by an opening and closing point, each of which we
will represent by an index giving the position in the data set. These indices can then be used to
look up the exact dates and prices at the opening and closing points of a position.

Comment: Look at the output dataset with the reworked input data I have used in pretty sure it does exactly what the question asks. If it needs counts of both open and closing positions that is easily done.

Comment: I understand what you mean I will fix it tomorrow. k, m, and s need to be user defined. You need a function to take your data frame, and values for k m and s to determine your open and close position dates.

Comment: ```                                                                                                                        for (i in seq_along(retail_stocks$ratio)) { 
      open_upper <- retail_stocks$ratio > (m + k*s) 
      open_lower <- retail_stocks$ratio < (m - k*s)
      close_upper <- retail_stocks$ratio <= m 
      close_lower <- retail_stocks$ratio >= m 
}

 if ((min(which(open_upper == TRUE))) < (min(which(open_lower == TRUE)))) {   pos <-  (min(which(open_upper == TRUE)))
   pos2 <- (min(which(close_upper == TRUE)))
  } else {
    min(which(open_lower == TRUE))
  }
 ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201530/discussion-between-eugenie-and-hello-friend).

Comment: @Eugenie please see amended answer

Comment: I looked at it, and tested it, but it doesn't give me the right indexes/positions. So i think we should leave it. if ((min(which((retail_stocks$ratio > (m + k*s))  == TRUE))) < (min(which((retail_stocks$ratio < (m - k*s)) == TRUE)))) {
  pos$open[i] <-  min(which(retail_stocks$ratio > (m + k*s)));
  pos$close[i] <- min(which(retail_stocks$ratio <= m))
} else {
  pos$open[i] <- min(which(retail_stocks$ratio < (m - k*s)))
} this only works for the first open. So im kind of stuck.

Comment: No worries if it’s not giving you the correct indices it’s because the formulas in the which clauses are wrong. I am using those you have provided above. If you can figure out the equation to classify open and close positions you can substitute into that function into a list data structure and subset the data frame using the indices stored in the list as shown.